не получается подключить css файл к html
первый раз работаю с css, а уже ничего не получается
вот весь код html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type = "text/css">
</head>
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error at quibusdam consequuntur sequi fugiat iure placeat repellat cumque eum eveniet commodi voluptate id, sed soluta voluptatem autem similique mollitia molestiae.
</body>
</html>

код css:
body {
    color:red;
}

путь к файлу точно введен правильно, я скопировала его полностью. переписывала код как вручную, так и копировала с разных сайтов. надеюсь на обратный отклик и заранее спасибо

В приведенном коде вообще нет указания пути к файлу css. Так же важно, как именно вы открываете данныую страницу, где именно, относительно вашего html файла лежит файл css. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, добавив(можно скрином) структуру проекта. И смотрите в devTools браузера во вкладке "сеть", есть ли там ошибки

Просто откройте страницу в режиме Просмотра кода страницы и найдите подключенный файл. Вполне возможно будет не правильно стоять путь к файлу css. И когда увидите путь к файлу, сразу поймёте, что упустили.

Атрибут href тега link как раз поможет вам задать путь к вашему css-файлу. Для этого укажите имя вашего css-файла, включая расширение - этого достаточно, если html и css-файлы расположены в одной папке. В ином случае вам следует указать путь к css-файлу.

я полностью указала путь к файлу, что и отметила в конце своего вопроса, тк мне не хотелось лишний раз его вводить. большое спасибо за ответ, я сама разобралась, почему у меня были проблемы с подключением (которые совершенно не связаны с путём)

У вас href="" пустой, как видите, там и нужно указать путь к вашему файлу стилей.

я полностью указала путь к файлу, что и отметила в конце своего вопроса, тк мне не хотелось лишний раз его вводить. большое спасибо за ответ, я сама разобралась, почему у меня были проблемы с подключением (которые совершенно не связаны с путём)

Если html и css в одной папке, достаточно в href указать: имя_файла.css
У вас не хватает расширения
Если нет, пишете путь

я полностью указала путь к файлу, что и отметила в конце своего вопроса, тк мне не хотелось лишний раз его вводить. большое спасибо за ответ, я сама разобралась, почему у меня были проблемы с подключением (которые совершенно не связаны с путём)
